# Chrome extension, check boxes that were dynamically added to the page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I am struggling to figure out how to check\uncheck check boxes with my chrome extension that are not part of the DOM when the page loads. In my example, if I make a simple page with checkboxes on them it works great, I click a button in my Chrome Extension and the checkboxes on the page basically toggle.

Now if I go to a page where the check boxes live in say a modal dialog where the dialog is loaded dynamically when opened, my extension is unable to check\uncheck the boxes.

Here is my setup.

I have a popup.html, popup.js & content.js. When you click a button in my popup.html it uses the messaging framework to send a message to the content script which then uses jQuery to check the boxes.

I have done some research on using mutationObservers but I cannot seem to get it to work. Can someone please help me understand how to tackle this.

Here is my code, for the content script I am using the else if block to check the boxes.

Any help is appreciated.

popup.js

```
    function hello() {

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "CheckAll"});
    });
  }



  document.getElementById('checkAll').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
        alert("background message:" + request.messgae);
        var firstHref = $("a[href^='http']").eq(0).attr("href");  
        console.log(firstHref);
        //Send this message to the background script
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "open_new_tab", "url": firstHref});
      }
      else if( request.message === "CheckAll" ) {             
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
          this.checked = true;                        
        });
      }
      else{
        //alert("nothing caught, here is the message:" + request.messgae);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Sounds like that modal dialog isn't using standard checkboxes, but just stylized div. Always start by debugging your code and inspecting the page.

Comment: Valid assumption, but unfortunately these are standard checkboxes.

Comment: Another *guess* would be the dialog is inside an iframe but your content script is not declared to run inside iframes.

Comment: Oooh, good thought, I have not checked that. Interestingly though, I have tried my same code on the w3schools "Try it yourself" page for checkboxes and it is also not working there either, that said, that could very well also be an iframe... I think I will create a test page where I dynamically add checkboxes and see if that works.

Comment: I totally missed the iFrame possibility, I had to add all_frames in the Manifest file and it started working. Thanks a ton